# Adding more advanced assertion to Python unittest

Tags: python, rest, api, unit-testing, python-unittest

I'm testing Trello API, creating and deleting cards. The only assertions I have here are for status code. How can I add some more 'advanced' assertions to the below code?

```
import unittest

from post_and_delete import *


class TestBasic(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_post_delete(self):
        # create new card with random name
        name = nonce(10)

        result_post = post(name)
        self.assertEqual(result_post.json()['name'], name)
        self.assertEqual(result_post.status_code, 200)

        card_id = result_post.json()['id']
        # get the card, verify it exists, status code should be 200
        result_get = get(card_id)
        self.assertEqual(result_get.status_code, 200)

        # delete the card, check again if status code is 200
        result = delete(card_id)
        self.assertEqual(result.status_code, 200)
        # get the recently deleted card, status code should be 404
        result_get = get(card_id)
        self.assertEqual(result_get.status_code, 404)

        # try to delete the card again, status code should be 404
        result = delete(card_id)
        self.assertEqual(result.status_code, 404)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: What else do you want to test? Why are all of the current tests in a single method?

Comment: Well, that's the other problem. I tried rewriting the code, so I would have three methods. (for get, post and delete). But then I was only posting new card, not deleting it.What I wanted to test, is for instance, the use of 'assertNotIn'

Comment: That hasn't really clarified much. Your successful deletion test would still have to start with creation, otherwise there's nothing to delete. I'm not sure why you feel you can't use `assertNotIn` - what do you want to test is in what else, and where's the problem in testing that?

Comment: I just think I wrongly use assertNotIn. I received 'JSONDecodeError', maybe it would be better to reorganize this code. Because you think that generally the above structure with single method is wrong, right?

Comment: Then **show a [mcve] of that**. Yes, the single method is wrong, each test case should be a separate method.